# How to decorate EntityManager on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I would like to decorate the entity manager so that I can do things before/after delegating the call to the persist method of the original one. Besides that, it is mandatory that the JPA repositories (interfaces inheriting `JpaRepository` use this decorated `EntityManager`). Solutions using aop/interception would be welcome as well as long as JPA repositories use the intercepted `EntityManager`.

For the sake of simplicity bellow is an example of the `EntityManager` decorator, bear in mind that even though I use this decorator to log something before/after delegating the call in the real scenario, I will not be using the decorator for logging.

```
public class CustomEntityManager implements EntityManager {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public CustomEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    ...

    public void persist(Object entity) {
        System.out.println("Before persisting...");
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        System.out.println("After persisting...");
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you try to find something like this http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-aop-with-spring-boot-starter-aop

Comment: PrePersist and PostPersist annotations may also be of help.